# Como tirar 6 fotos Seguidas apenas usando o Kivy?

Tags: kivy

Queria um exemplo de como tirar 6 fotos Seguidas usando kivy.uix.camera.
Observação: Sem mandar consultar o site de exemplos da Kivy, todos os exemplos que eu vi tinham comentários falando para ler o documento do Kivy, mas eu não achei ainda essa função para foto.

Answer (score 1):

E não é só chamar 6 vezes a função?

```
camera = Camera(play=False)

camera.export_to_png('c:/fotos/1.png')
camera.export_to_png('c:/fotos/2.png')
camera.export_to_png('c:/fotos/3.png')
camera.export_to_png('c:/fotos/4.png')
camera.export_to_png('c:/fotos/5.png')
camera.export_to_png('c:/fotos/6.png')
```

Ou com `for`:

```
for i in range(1, 6):
    camera.export_to_png('c:/fotos/' + str(i) + '.png')
```

E se quiser de meio em meio segundo não seria apenas aplicar um simples sleep?

```
import time

camera = Camera(play=False)

for i in range(1, 6):
    camera.export_to_png('c:/fotos/' + str(i) + '.png')
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

Se sabe usar Python e conhece o `time.sleep` então sabe que dá pra trabalhar com segundos ou valores menores, no exemplo foi meio segundo com 0.5, se for intervalo de um segundo:

```
time.sleep(1)
```

Não creio que haja complexidade, acho que talvez você esteja esperando que a API faça algo que deveria fazer parte do seu algoritmo, é uma critica construtiva, não adianta querer fazer o avançado se você pular o básico da linguagem de programação e me parece que sua falta de entendimento é no básico do Python e não no uso do Kivy